# Submit multiple checkboxes values

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, checkbox

jquery:

```
(...)
$('#button_submit').click(function() 
{                           
func(check_box_values) 
});
```

html:

```
<form id="myForm">
<label class="checkbox">
<input type="checkbox" name="my_opt[]" value="1">opt1</label>
<label class="checkbox">
<input type="checkbox" name="my_opt[]" value="2">opt2</label>
<label class="checkbox">
<input type="checkbox" name="my_opt[]" value="3">opt3</label>
<input id='my_opt' type='hidden' name='my_opt[]' />
<input type="button" id="button_submit" value="go">
</form>
```

How could I pass this checked checkboxes values up there to use in `func(check_box_values)` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [`.map()`](http://api.jquery.com/map/) method for that:

```
var check_box_values = $('#myForm [type="checkbox"]:checked').map(function () {
    return this.value;
}).get();
```

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/DADTd/)

#### Explanation

- `$('#myForm [type="checkbox"]:checked')` selects the elements that are descendants of `#myForm`, have a `type` attribute with the value `checkbox`, and are checked.
- The `.map()` method iterates on the result elements, and the value that is returned in the function (which will be the `value` of the element, because here `this refers to the actual DOM element) is added to a collection.
- In the end, `.get()` is used to convert the collection into a simple Javascript array.

Comment: I forgot to say that I should be able to work with checkbox values further. Eg. `if (check_box_values === 1) // something` Is that possible with your solution ?

Comment: @skdnewbie The values will be collected into an array (named `check_box_values`). You can do anything with the array, like using jQuery's `inArray()` method on it to check if a certain value is in there. If the first two checkboxes are checked, the array will be `[1,2]` containing the values of the checked checkboxes.

Comment: surely you've realized that I'm beginner, so I will ask you, and im sorry, how can I get the array values then. And thanks, this is what i was looking for

Comment: @skdnewbie For example, to check if `2` is in the array, you would write `if ($.inArray('2', check_box_values) > -1) { //it's fine }` using [`$.inArray()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/). You can read about [arrays on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) for example, it's knowledge you cannot succeed without.

Comment: how difficult it is if I want to pass only the unchecked values?

Comment: @skdnewbie One way is `:not(:checked)` instead of `:checked`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want all checkbox elements (not just the checked ones), try this. This doesn't use jQuery.

```
var formEl = document.getElementById('myForm'),
    inputs = formEl.getElementsByTagName('input'),
    numInputs = inputs.length,
    checkboxEls = [];

while(numInputs--) {
    if (inputs[numInputs].getAttribute('type') == 'checkbox') checkboxEls.push(inputs[numInputs]);
}

func(checkboxEls);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code, if you want to get the value of the checkbox.

```
$("#button_submit").on("click",function(){
    $("#myForm input").each(function(){
         var Check = $('#chkSelect');
         if(Check.is(':checked') == true){
             func(Check.attr('value'));
         }
    });
});
```

this code will create a loop on the entire form and check if whether the check box is check or not, then call the func function in your code.